# Huawei Account Kit fingerprint certificate is correctly configured, but it still throws the error code 6003

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I am am trying to integrate Huawei Account kit to my application.

I am referring to codelab guide on this link : https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSAccounts/index.html#0

But when I try to run the application, it throws me an error with code 6003.

On the website, it says it is caused because if fingerprint certificate is not configured. I did configure it and I am still having the same error. Any advice on what might be going wrong and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps you need to check :

1. Enable the service and download the agconnect-services.json file again.
2. Android Studio->Build->Clean Project
3. Clear the HMS Core (APK) cache.
4. Please  recheck that the correct certificate fingerprint is configured when applying for related services. Open the APK of the application, unzip the meta-inf folder, and get the CERT.RSA File, via keytool - printcert - file meta-inf/ CERT.RSA Command to print the signature certificate information.
5. Log in to appgallery connect and click "my application". After entering the application development page, check whether the fingerprint configured in "sha256 certificate fingerprint" is consistent with that in step 1 in "Development > Overview".